# include_path won't work on PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, include-path

I have a construct function where I am using `include_path`, the function looks like this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $url = $this->parseUrl();

    if(file_exists('application\controllers'.$url[0].'.php')){

        $this->controller=$url[0];
        unset($url[0]);
    }

    require_once 'application\controllers'.$this->controller.'.php';


    echo $this->controller;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to load an existing controller url like this one `http://localhost/project/public_html/home` I get the following error :

```
Warning: require_once(application\controllers home.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\core\App.php on line 24

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'application\controllers home.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\core\App.php on line 24
```

I followed the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-include-paths.html) and I included the paths :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application
```

and

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\application\controllers
```

but I am still getting the error and I am just clueless why... can someone help me?

Comment: You're probably missing an '\', it sould be 'application\controllers\'.$this->controller.'.php';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you have a space in the path...is that normal?
Can you try with 'application\controllers' (without space there) please?
And controllershome.php is the name of file, or controllers/home.php?

Comment: No, but it still does not work after removing the space

Comment: Use / instead of \ . Path is calculated from the current file location. If you have folder X containing file Y and folder Z, if you are in a file from folder Z, include file Y like this '../Y'. ../ is used to go back one folder from your current path